# Does the theory fit the given data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, maximum-likelihood, goodness-of-fit

We are given that the members of a community are classified by blood type according to the following schema:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
O& A & B & AB & Total \\ \hline
121 & 120 & 79 & 33 & 353\\ \hline
\end{array}

We are also given that the probabilities of the above blood types depend on gene frequency parameters $r, p, q$ satisfying the following relations:

$$
r + p + q = 1
$$
$$
P(\text{O}) = r^2
$$
$$
P(\text{A}) = p^2 + 2pr
$$
$$
P(\text{B}) = q^2 + 2qr
$$
$$
P(\text{AB}) = 2pq
$$
Finally, we are given the MLEs of the $p,q, r$, which are:
$$
\hat{r} = 0.580
$$
$$
\hat{p} = 0.246
$$
$$
\hat{q} = 0.173
$$
My question is, what is the approach to testing if the given community fits the theory. Typically the approach is to use a $\chi^2$ test for goodness of fit but I cannot see how it would apply in this scenario. Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
It was brought to my attention that I am not exactly stating what aspect of the test I am not understanding. Here is that information:

1. I am assuming that $H_0$ in this case will be that the proposed theory fits the data and $H_1$ that it does not.
2. There does not seem to be a preferred level of significance so I goes 5% should be acceptable (if there is motivation to choose a different one, please let me know)
3. The degrees of freedom will be 3(?)
4. For expected frequencies I should have e.g. $0 \times P(\text{0}) = 121 \times 0.580^2 $ and so on.
5. The observed data is given and the test statistic is easy to compute.

Is the summary I have provided the way to tackle this or am I missing some aspect of the problem?

**UPDATE 2**:
It was mentioned to me that the degrees of freedom should be less than 3 because of the MLEs. It is not clear to me how this happens exactly. Could someone elaborate on this aspect of the problem?

Comment: Could you explain more specifically what you think the obstacle to applying a $\chi^2$ test would be?  It looks like all the pieces are there: the data and the information needed to estimate expected frequencies for the cells.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have updated the question to reflect your point.

Comment: Given the MLEs (which do not quite add up to $1$ due to rounding), the expected number type O should be $353 \times 0.580^2$

Comment: I suspect the number of degrees of freedom is less than $3$ given the calculation of MLEs

Comment: @Henry Your comment about DFs is interesting. Could you elaborate a bit more on how should I count the DFs for this problem?

Comment: It appears to be the case that $df = k -1 - m$, where $k$ is the number of cells and $m$ is the number of parameters estimated. That would leave me with $0$ dfs for this problem,

Comment: You only have 2 df in the parameter estimation since the third parameter is obtained by subtraction from 1.